# Как вывести картинку GIF

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как показать каритнку формата GIF используя специальные классы каких-либо библиотек обработки формата. Язык C++

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [D3DXCreateTextureFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172801(v=vs.85).aspx) из DirectX, Ну а можно через стандартную [LoadBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033(v=vs.85).aspx)

А вот ещё целая [заметка](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/qna/gdi/drawimg.xml) есть по этому поводу

Answer (score 0):

Для VC++ и MFC [здесь](http://subscribe.ru/archive/comp.soft.prog.qandacpp/200411/26162734.html#inf6). 
Для BCB смотри тоже в просторах сети.